# Jplayer - not work in Opera correctly

Tags: opera, jplayer

I have some trouble with Jplayer. One block has two links to 2 mp3 tracks. Sing 1 and Sing 2. FF, IE, Safari and Chrome work with them by Jplayer correctly. But Opera dont.

```
$("#media01").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {            
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"/files/sing01.mp3"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "/scripts/js/",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window"
});
$('.popup-player a#media01').click(function(){
    $("a#media02").removeClass('active');
    $("#media02").jPlayer("pause");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $("#media01").jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"/files/sing01.mp3"
        }).jPlayer("play");
    } else {
        $("#media01").jPlayer("pause");
    }
});
```

//  Second //

```
$("#media02").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {            
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"/files/sing02.mp3"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "/scripts/js/",
    supplied: "mp3",
    wmode: "window"
});
$('.popup-player a#media02').click(function(){
    $("a#media01").removeClass('active');
    $("#media01").jPlayer("pause");
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $("#media02").jPlayer("setMedia", {
            mp3:"/files/sing02.mp3"
        }).jPlayer("play");
    } else {
        $("#media02").jPlayer("pause");
    }
});
```

JS and JQuery - level bad :(

In Opera dont play tracks, or play one of this random, or play 0.5 sec of last

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set the fallback?

```
solution: "flash, html", // Flash with an HTML5 fallback.
```

or

```
solution: "html, flash", // HTML5 with an Flash fallback.
```